# How to parse to a type in Scala

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I'm trying to write a parser in Scala that gradually builds up a concrete type hierarchy. I started with:

```
private def word   = regex(new Regex("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*")) 
private def quicktoken: Parser[Quicktoken] = "/" ~> word <~ "/" <~ (space?) ^^ { new Quicktoken(_) }
```

which is fine. /hello/ will get parsed to a quicktoken

Now I want to add the quicktoken to a composite expression. I have a class

```
class MatchTokenPart(word:String,quicktoken:RewriteWord){
}
```

I would have thought that I could write...

```
private def matchTokenPartContent: Parser[MatchTokenPart] = word<~equals~quicktoken ^^ { case word~quicktoken => new MatchTokenPart(word, quicktoken)}
```

but it doesn't work. It says that word is of type Option[String] and quicktoken of type String. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another precedence issue: `a <~ b ~ c` is interpreted as `a <~ (b ~ c)`, not `(a <~ b) ~ c`. This is because infix operators starting with `<` have lower precedence than ones starting with `~`, (see the list in 6.12.3 of [the language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)).

You want `(word <~ equals) ~ quicktoken`, so you'll need to supply the parentheses.